# Startup application not working

Tags: 14.04, startup-applications

I put this in my Startup Applications

```
synclient PalmDetect=1 PalmMinWidth=5 PalmMinZ=20
```

But I noticed that this doesn't take effect when the machine is restarted.  Am I doing something wrong here?  This is being done in Ubuntu 14.04.

[image: adding a startup command]

Comment: Check whether the command in use is correct. This link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingProgramToSessionStartup will guide you in adding the programs in startup just in case you have missed anything. Also check the link http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1767979 to add applications through command line

Comment: @vembutech: The Community Help Wiki page you mentioned is dated. There is a new [Startup Applications](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html) page now in the official documentation, but I don't think the OP needs it. If the command changes the behavior when run in a terminal window, I can't tell either why it doesn't work via Startup Applications.